# Why does nvmlDeviceGetTemperature only work in debug mode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nvml

Using VS2022 the following code snippet works in debug mode but not in release mode:

```
nvmlInit();
nvmlDevice_t devH;
auto ret = nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex_v2(0, &devH);
if (ret != NVML_SUCCESS)  DPrint("ERROR!");

u32 tt{};
ret = nvmlDeviceGetTemperature(devH, NVML_TEMPERATURE_GPU, &tt);
if (ret != NVML_SUCCESS)  DPrint("%s\n\n", nvmlErrorString(ret));

DPrint("TEMP:  %u\n", tt);

Sleep(10000);
```

In release mode I get `NOT SUPPORTED` but in debug mode it works fine, printing the temperature.  I have checked all the properties especially the linker ones and I cannot find any significant differences that would explain it.  `DPrint` is a simple utility to print to the output window.

Comment: Maybe that function is just not implemented in the release library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the release build was loading a different version of nvml.dll.  Fixed it and now it works!